# Jquerymobile/Phonegap/iOS footer navbar not fixed upon first scroll

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a multi-page Jquerymobile 1.2 file.  When I navigate to a page that requires scroll, the footer is no longer fixed, but jumps upon the first scroll.  When I release my finger, the footer jumps back into place.  This effect no longer occurs when I repeat the process on any other page within the multi-page document with a subsequent scroll.

Here is the code for the footer - this is used for all pages within the multi-page document (please note that it links to a couple of external files as well):

```
<div data-role="footer" class="nav-rp" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed" data-id="myfooter">
    <div data-role="navbar" class="nav-rp" >
        <ul>
            <li><a rel="external" href="index.html#index"  class="icon-index" data-icon="custom">Home</a></li>
            <li><a rel="external" href="index.html#route-1" class="icon-route" data-icon="custom">Route</a></li>
            <li><a rel="external" href="gallery.html" class="icon-gallery" data-icon="custom">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="businesses.html" rel="external" class="icon-business" data-icon="custom">Business</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think I have fixed my issue - it was related to the meta viewport tag at the top.  I included height=device-height and that seemed to do the trick.

Comment: This is the answer, bu to be more specific on <head></head> use  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height , initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

Answer (score 1):

Here are some interesting trick to fix this

```js
$('body').animate({scrollTop: window.screen.availHeight}, 1, function(){
        $('body').animate({scrollTop: "0px"}, 1);
    })
```

perfectly works in iOS with any fixed element

Answer (score 0):

This happens with `ios 5.11` (Running on iPhone 3Gs), `ios 6.12` (Runninig on iPhone4) , `ios 6.0.1`  (Running on iPhone 5).
My app is running with `Phonegap 2.3`.

This problem is not just `jQueryMobile` issue but a css position fixed issue. (or something else that is manifestated with the css issue)

The "fixed" footer starts moving on the first scroll. After this the footer is fixed. And every time the onscreen keyboard is popped up and the content is scrolled, the footer is loose again.

The answer suggested by @VoVaVc fixes the first scroll issue, but not the keyboard open  scroll issue. The declaration `height=device-height` that fixed it for Studio4 did nothing whatsoever for my app.

html:

```
 <div id="footernav">
            <div id="Button" class="navButton">
                <img class="naviImg" src="assets/icon.png">
                <span>###buttonTexts###</span>
            </div>
            <div id="secondButton" class="navButton">
                <img class="naviImg" src="assets/icon.png">
                <span>###buttonTexts###</span>
            </div>                
  </div>
```

And the css for the container

```
#footernav {
clear: both;
position: fixed !important;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 9%;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 -3px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
box-shadow:0 -3px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
z-index: 9;
}
```

EDIT:

I solved my problem with the mother of all hacks:

```
    $('.formularInputRecipient', this.el).on('focus',function() {
        console.log("HIDE");
        $("#footernav", this.el).hide();
    });


    $('.formularInputRecipient', this.el).on('blur',function() {
        console.log("show");
        $("#footernav", this.el).show();
    });
```

SO. The keyboard messes with the fixed footer. So when ever I get the onscreen keyboard (in my case, clicking on the text input fields) I hide the footer that is in the wrong place and when closing the keyboard, I show it again.

Sometimes there is no time for proper solutions.